# General Race Condition

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am new to C and wanted to know about race conditions. I found this on the internet and it asked to find the race condition, and a solution to it.

My analysis is that the race condition is in the create-thread() method has the race condition, specifically in the `if-else` statement. So when the method is being accessed another thread could be created or removed during the `check-and-act` and the thread_amt would be off.

In order to not have the race condition, then lock the `if-else` using mutex, semaphores, etc?

Can anyone correct me if I am wrong, and could possibly show me how to implement mutex?

```
#define MAXT 255
int threads_amt = 0;
int create-thread() // create a new thread
{
    int tid;
    if (threads_amt == MAXT) return -1;
    else
    {
        threads_amt++;
        return tid;
    }
}
void release-thread()
{
    /* release thread resources */
    --threads_amt;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a link to wherever you found this..... thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the race condition in this case happens because you have no guarantee that the checking and the manipulation of `threads_amt` are going to happen with no interruption/execution of another thread.

Three solutions off the top of my head:

1) Force mutual exclusion to that part of code using a binary semaphore (or mutex) to protect the if-else part.

2) Use a semaphore with initial value MAXT, and then, upon calling create_thread (mind, you can't use hyphens in function names!), use "wait()" (depending on the type of semaphore, it could have different names (such as sem_wait())). After that, create the thread. When calling release_thread(), simply use "signal()" (sem_post(), when using `semaphore.h`).

3) This is more of an "hardware" solution: you could assume that you are given an atomic function that performs the entire if-else part, and therefore avoids any race condition problem.

Of these solutions, the "easiest" one (based on the code you already have) is the first one.

Let's use `semaphore.h`'s semaphores:

```
#define MAXT 255

// Global semaphore 
sem_t s;
int threads_amt = 0;

int main () {
    ...
    sem_init (&s, 0, 1); // init semaphore (initial value = 1)
    ...
}


int create_thread() // create a new thread
{
    int tid;
    sem_wait(&s);
    if (threads_amt == MAXT) {
        sem_post(&s); // the semaphore is now available
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        threads_amt++;
        sem_post(&s); // the semaphore is now available
        return tid;
    }
}
void release_thread()
{
    /* release thread resources */
    sem_wait(&s);
    --threads_amt;
    sem_post(&s);
}
```

This should work just fine.

I hope it's clear. If it's not, I suggest that you study how semaphores work (use the web, or buy some Operating System book). Also, you mentioned that you are new to C: IMHO you should start with something easier than this: semaphores aren't exactly the next thing you want to learn after the 'hello world' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The race condition is not in the `if()` statements.

It is with access to the variable `threads_amt` that is potentially changed and accessed at the same time in multiple threads.

Essentially, any thread that modifies the variable must have exclusive access to avoid a race condition.   That means all code which modifies the variable or reads its value must be synchronised (e.g. grab a mutex first, release after).   Readers don't necessarily need exclusive access (e.g. two threads reading at the same time won't necessarily affect each other) but writers do (so avoid reading a value while trying to change it in another thread) - such considerations can be opportunities to use synchronisation methods other than a mutex - for example, semaphores.

To use a mutex, it is necessary to create it first (e.g. during project startup).   Then grab it when needed, and remember to release it when done.  Every function should minimise the time that it holds the mutex, since other threads trying to grab the mutex will be forced to wait.

The trick is to make the grabbing and releasing of the mutex unconditional, wherever it occurs (i.e. avoid a function that grabs the mutex, being able to return without releasing it).   That depends on how you structure each function.

The actual code for implementing depends on which threading library you're using (so you need to read the documentation) but the concepts are the same.   All threading libraries have functions for creating, grabbing (or entering), and releasing mutexes, semaphores, etc etc.

Comment: Technically you are right, race conditions happen when multiple threads have access (as writers) to same memory block at the same time. But, in this specific case, the problem is with the fact that threads_amt is first checked and then, some instructions later, it is modified with the assumption that nothing has happened to the variable since the check: this could lead to a number of threads >= MAXT. That's why I would say that the problem is with the if-else statement ("check-then-act", as it is sometimes called).